# Stop Javascript and Continue after User interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i got a mind/memory game in javascript where you can play against the computer. If two Cards match a popup appears. The Problem is that when the Computer finds these two cards and the popup appears, he continues playing in the background of the popup. I want the script to stop and continue when the user closes the popup.

Heres the piece of code where the popup is included (i did it as an alert. is there another way to do this?)

```
function checkIdentity()
{
    if(clicks[0].imageNum == clicks[1].imageNum)
    {
        countPairs();
        imagesInGame.deleteElementByValue(clicks[0].imageNum, 'imageNum');
        openedImages.deleteElementByValue(clicks[0].imageNum, 'imageNum');
           alert(messages[clicks[1].imageNum]);  

        gotLastPair = player;
        waitASecond = false;
        clicks.clean();
    checkForGameEnd();
    }
    else
    {
        allPlayers[player]['failures']++;
        turnId = setTimeout(function() { hidePics() }, timeout);
    }
}
var Alert = new CustomAlert();

var messages = 
{
    1: "pop up message",
    2: "pop up message",
    3: "pop up message",
    4: "pop up message",
    5: "pop up message",
    6: "pop up message",
    7: "pop up message",
    8: "pop up message",
    9: "pop up message",
    10: "pop up message",
    11: "pop up message",
    12: "pop up message",
    13: "pop up message",
}
```

and this is what the computer opponent does

```
function checkForPairsInOpenedImages(obj)
{
    if(obj)
    {
        for(var i=0; i<openedImages.length; i++)
        {
            if(obj.divNum != i && openedImages[i].imageNum == obj.imageNum)
            {
                computerPics.push(openedImages[i]);
            return true;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(var i=0; i<openedImages.length; i++)
        {
            for(var j=0; j<openedImages.length; j++)
            {
                if(j != i && openedImages[j].imageNum == openedImages[i].imageNum)
                {
                    computerPics.push(openedImages[i]);
                    computerPics.push(openedImages[j]);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}

function computerShowPics()
{
    setTimeout( function() { showPic(computerPics[0], true) }, 500);
    setTimeout( function() { showPic(computerPics[1], true) }, 1500);
}
```

Comment: Can you put a comment in your code where this popup is triggered and then another comment in your code where you want it to continue to execute

Comment: When invoking popup you could set some variable "allow_play" to false, and computer would always compare to this value whether it's true or not, so when it wouldn't it won't continue to choose cards